# Printing the ASCII value (not character) in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii, dos

I'm a newbie with assembly language and I'd like to display the ASCII value of a character which I have stored in register CX.

Any ideas how to do it? Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: what do you mean by _display_?

Comment: What OS are you targeting?

Comment: when i use mov dx,cx;mov ah,2;int 21h, there will be printed a character, and i want to print ascii number of that character